# problems with accessing services via jquery with ssl / https

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, ssl, webforms

we register our Services in a base page :

```
protected void RegisterService(string path)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Services.Add(new ServiceReference(path));
}
```

and then in the client side ( javascript ) - we address them with :

```
Invoice.{serviceName}.{functionName}
```

the "Invoice" is the name space , without the SSL ( without https:// ) there is no problem addressing the WCF from the js file , with the SSL - it doesn't recognize our services - notice that the web.config is set to https , also when trying to approach them directly :

```
https://domain.com/{serviceName}.svc
```

it works fine.

any ideas ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/65r14d - Invoice is not defined